# Connections using websockets using express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sockets, websocket

I am new at nodejs and websockets and i would like to have some explanation about this theme. I've already search over the internet and i can only find client/server connections and that is not what i am searching.

Basically, i have a nodejs server named "servertes.js" with localhost:8080 that is hosting my webpage.

I need to send requests from my webpage to one external server "extServer.js" with 127.0.0.1:3000 that is already made and i don't have control over it. The only server that i have control is "servertest.js".

All the requests must be received by servertest.js that sends the request to the extServer.js and vice-versa.

```
      ---------           ---------------         --------------
     | Webpage | <------>| servertest.js |<----->| extServer.js |
      ---------           ---------------         --------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this scenario you act as the client from your controlled server. Sockets are always host/server to client/receiver.

Comment: You are saying that i need to create a websocket between webpage and servertest and then create a websocket between servertest and extserver? I need to send the client request to servertest and from servertest to extserver? If that is the case, how can i create a connection between them? Do you suggest a websocket inside a websocket? Sorry for the ignorance

Comment: Yes in this scenario you need two sockets. The middle layer would act as a client to one side and as a server to the other

Comment: Last question websocket server inside the websocket client  or websocket client inside the websocket server? Thank you for the help